# Assign one TCHAR value to another

Tags: c++, winapi

I have one `TCHAR` array that I want to assign to another. For example:

```
TCHAR tchar1[ MAX_PATH ],tchar2[ MAX_PATH ];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0,tchar1, CSIDL_MYPICTURES, FALSE);
tchar2=tchar1; //something like this
```

Anyone have idea?

Comment: you will need to roll out a for loop

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what a TCHAR is, but if they follow the same convention as C strings, you could use `strcpy(tchar2,tchar1)`.

Comment: @amaurea In the Win32 API, `TCHAR` is either `char`or `wchar_t` wether `UNICODE` is defined or not.

Comment: `_tcscpy(tchar2, tchar1)` will do it (Windows only, obviously)

Comment: @zakinster: Thanks. The question should probably be tagged with winapi or similar to make it clear that this isn't standard C++.

Comment: @amaurea I've edited the tags - you can do it also by the way (in case you weren't aware).

Comment: @JBentley: Thanks. I know I can edit the tags, but I didn't know which tag was appropriate here.

Comment: shouldn't this question be tagged as C? there is no C++ in it (in which case I would suggest using std::basic_string<TCHAR>)

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Not necessarily, the OP could be using C-style code with a C++ compiler. It's better to stick to the OP's choice of tag unless the question specifically contradicts it IMO.

Comment: Sure, but there is not a single thing in the question which is C++ specific. That way, every C question could be tagged as C++.

Answer (score 7):

You got two char arrays. They cannot be assigned to each other, their contents have to be copied.

To copy TCHAR arrays [_tcscpy_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9(v=vs.80).aspx) is the way to go (to make it compile with and without UNICODE defined ... which would be the only reason to use TCHAR in the first place).

Comment: it should be noted that _tcscpy_s is specific to MS CRT (although the question is obviously target at Windows)

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic So is `TCHAR`.

Comment: TCHAR is not specific to MS, e.g. Borland C++ Builder also supports it, you might say it is specific to Windows. However, it is just a typedef so it is not hard to port it, unlike _tcsscpy_s.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `tchar2=tchar1;` would not compile as these variables are array. Have they been declared as `TCHAR*` it would compile, but it wouldn't work as desired, since it would just assign the pointer values, it would not copy one string to the other.

You can use [`_tcsncpy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdsywd25%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [`_tcscpy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) functions:

```
_tcscpy(tchar2, tchar1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`lstrcpyn()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647491.aspx) or equivilent function:

```
lstrcpyn(tchar2, tchar1, MAX_PATH);
```

Comment: Right at the top of the documentation from the link it says `Warning Do not use.`

Comment: @JoelRondeau: I did say "or equivalent" :) Not all systems have the newer functions.

Comment: Agreed. I was commenting as a warning to people who might not click on the link. I wouldn't -1 you for it or anything.